# React is not updating the passing prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring, react-state

I'm destructuring variable from React state in render() of my class component like this:

```
let { indexTabPoints } = this.state;
```

After that I'm changing it's value:

```
if (condition) {
  indexTabPoints += 1;
  console.log(indexTabPoints); // value's changing as it should
}
```

And then I'm passing indexTabPoints as a prop to another component:

```
<PointTab
  activeIndex={indexTabPoints}
  ....
/>
```

Afterwards I'm checking the value of activeIndex in PointTab component and see an old value (without any changes).

It seems to me, that React does not update the prop I'm passing to PointTab component, whenever it's changing or not. Why is this happening and how to avoid it, using destructuring?

Edited:
I've just noticed that i got several  child components and the other one (in another place) was telling me that the value is old (because for it the value did not change).
Thank you all guys for help, forgive me my carelessness.

Comment: Please provide minimum not working example becouse code you provide is fine

Comment: `indexTabPoints += 1;` What circumstances are you doing this in? Is this just part of the calculations you're doing in `render()`? Or is some event happening (say, an onClick) and you're trying to update the value then?

Comment: For now (for tests) the condition is just (true), but in fact it is true when some other variables have the values i need. Nothing calculates in condition itself.

Answer (score 2):

Props are immutable

And you can't update state like `indexTabPoints += 1;`, instead you can do like `this.setState((prev) =>({indexTabPoints: prev+1}))`, and you shoul not log states value just after setting it since setState is asynchronous while the console.log is executed immediately

Can try this (but just for debugging):

```
if (condition) {
 indexTabPoints += 1;
 setTimeout(() => console.log(indexTabPoints), 1000);
}
```

example for debugging to understand if component is called before if condition:

```
if (condition) {
 indexTabPoints += 1;
 console.log("in if condition" + indexTabPoints);
}


render(){
   return(
     {
       console.log(" in render" + indexTabPoints)
     }
     <PointTab
       activeIndex={indexTabPoints}
       ....
     />);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i use destructured variable while passing the prop to another component, not the state value itself, so this.setState() will change the value in state, but not the destructured variable, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.
The "if condition" is in child component or parent only?

Comment: In parent only. And then I'm checking passed prop value at the start of child component, without any ifs.

Comment: Might be, component is called before the value is changes, so i would suggest refer example above for debugging

Comment: Well, even without setTimeout it shows the correct value (including +1), but another console.log (in the component where i passed indexTabPoints) it logs the old value anyway (not including +1).

Comment: Can you refer above second example to debug?

Comment: Sry, haven't seen the edited answer.
The "if (condition) {" construction is inside render method in my code. But i think i've found the problem and checking it right now, so will text in few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239205/discussion-between-vishwa-and-jorah-m).